# Sneaky vocabulary connections between areas of math

Tags: terminology, big-list

As you learn more math you better appreciate the way things are named. So when I see things with the same name I wonder if there is some sneaky connection between them.

1. Does the trace operator for PDE have anything to do with the trace of an operator?
2. Does the spectrum of an operator have anything to do with the prime spectrum of a ring?
3. Does anyone have more examples?

Comment: Group actions can be transitive.  Relations can be transitive.  [Are they related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393513/what-is-the-connection-between-group-action-transitivity-and-relation-transitivi) I don't know.

Comment: Conversely, [this guy showed up to ask about topologically closed sets and closed binary operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150351/definition-of-closed) and a lot of people agreed in the comments that there was no connection, even though I think the connection is obvious.